# Understanding Google Analytics OAuth offline access

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics

I've been struggling trying to understand how [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) 2.0 offline access works practically and how to implement it into my PHP script.

I have multiple websites, each with their own Google account, that I use to get their Google Analytics information for a report. I have a script which gets the information however I need to be logged into their particular Google email for the script to run, otherwise I get an error saying I don't have permission for that account. For example:

Email 1 has access for Website A and Website B.

Email 2 has access for Website C and Website D.

So if I want to run a report for Website D I have to log in into Email 2. Then afterwards if I need to run a report for Website A, I will have to log out of Email 2 and log in to Email 1.

As there are going to be potentially hundreds of websites, all on different emails, I cannot keep doing it this way. The way in which I want it to work is if I am in a main Email and can run reports for as many Websites as I need.

I have researched into this and found that there is an setAccessType('offline') feature for OAuth 2.0 that sounds like it will solve all my problems. However, I can't get my head around how it actually works and what I need to do to allow access from the Websites. I have read the documents and tried, but nothing I try seems to work.

Do I need to store something in a database? If I do how do I access the thing to store it?

What does the code look like?

What I am currently using regarding the OAuth:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets/clientName/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])){
        $resp = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $array = get_object_vars(json_decode($resp));
    }

    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client); // Getting interface provided by service object

    $accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();
```

I use the $accounts to get all the information I need for example:

```
$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
                                        'ga:' . $viewId, //profile
                                        $startDate,
                                        $endDate,
                                        'ga:goalCompletionsAll', // metrics
                                        $optParams
                                    );
```

I can get the results and put them into a report but that is pretty much all I know about Google Analytics.

How do I get the offline to work or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It seems you are able to retrieve the data, so what is your problem ?

Comment: Yes I can retrieve the data however I have to be logged into the client's google account. When there are hundreds this won't be feasible. I need to be able to get the data while not logged on to their google account. This is where the offline feature comes in but even with the documentation with it I can't understand how to use it. So my question is how do you use the access type offline? I have tried but cant get it to work.

Comment: You can use a service account (anonymous account created via the API console) but even that needs to be added to every account that you want to query. Linda Lawton (DaimTo on SO) has a PHP Tutorial for service accounts on her website: http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/

Comment: I can't get one account on all of the clients Google Analytics account.